# QT не получается скачать файл по URL

Tags: qt, qt5

Доброе! Не подскажете где ошибаюсь?

```
form1.h

private slots:
        void onResultJson(QNetworkReply *reply);

private:
    Ui::Form1 *ui;
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager;
};
```

form1.cpp:

```
Form1::Form1(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),    
    ui(new Ui::Form1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QNetworkReply* mNetReply = nullptr;
    mNetReply=networkManager->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://xn--90acbu5aj5f.xn--p1ai/files/json")));   
    connect(mNetReply,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(onResultJson(QNetworkReply*)));
   ...
void Form1::onResultJson(QNetworkReply *reply){
    qDebug() << reply;
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Object::connect: No such signal
>   QNetworkReplyImpl::finished(QNetworkReply*) in
>   ../sbssalert/form1.cpp:19 Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'Form1')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам текст ошибки все говорит - сигнала с сигнатурой `finished(QNetworkReply*)` нет. Согласно документации сигнал `finished()` без параметров. Чтобы ваш код заработал, надо строку с соединением переписать так:

```
connect(mNetReply,SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onResultJson()));
```

Соответственно, понадобится изменить сигнатуру слота `onResultJson`, убрав из него указатель на `QNetworkReply`

Для доступа к объекту, бросившему сигнал, воспользуйтесь методом `sender()` в слоте, он вернет вам указатель на объект, который испустил сигнал, приведший к вызову этого слота. То есть в вашем случае код слота `onResultJson` будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
QNetworkReply * reply = qobject_cast<QNetworkReply *>(sender());
qDebug() << reply;
```